# Change tomcat base URL

Tags: java, tomcat, lighttpd

I have a front facing lighttpd server on my domain that redirects a specific URL to a tomcat 8 application server. So, traffic to mydomain.com/app will be pushed to tomcat.

Tomcat, however, sees the "app" portion of the url and tries to match it when serving requests from the default webapp directory location - resulting in 404's for everything. Is there a configuration change I can make to tomcat so that it knows to look that default webapp directory for requests that come from "/app"?

For example, I'd like to access my web application at mydomain.com/app/mywebapp  -  tomcat should still look for the application at /usr/lib/tomcat8/webapps/mywebapp.

Comment: sounds like [`tomcat virtual domain`](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/virtual-hosting-howto.html) to me

Answer (score 7):

After a few hours of hair-pulling I found an answer to my own question [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/380200/adding-a-global-uri-prefix-for-tomcat-web-apps).

It seems that Apache has made this configuration possible not by editing any configuration but by editing file names under the application root.